# Is that a bug? Circular dependency on images

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

Im trying to bake textures, and i get this circular dependency even if i got 2 materials and its pretty straight forward plug 1 map in its socket. And this causes map that im baking to ignore that texture. But what makes me think that it is a bug of some sort is that if i replace this texture(delete and plug same one) it works just fine[image]

[image]

[image]

So here is an example with 2 materials, some basic stuff
And here is what happens when i hit bake :/

Comment: maybe give some screenshots or even share your file (with the images packed witihn): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: added screenshots. i should mention this only occurs if i bake on copies of blendfiles that contain packed images. but its not for every image/material this happens, only some. Also as you might imagine it modifies both of those(no surprise here im guessing)

Comment: hard to understand with only screenshots, when you bake you need to select the Image Texture node with the image that is supposed to receive the bake picture, also there might be a refresh problem, so try to unplug and replug the Image Texture into the socket?

Comment: yes, that workes if you unplug it(well i deleted and plugin from new one it but same thing). Guess it is just a refresh problem , not a bug , ty